# No change in loss or accuracy when training BertForSequenceClassification

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have text data for court cases that I am trying to classify with a binary classification as a 0 or 1 representing the first or second party wining.I have the following code to create the datasets:

```
class TextDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor(int(self.labels[idx]))
        type(item)
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

train_encodings = tokenizer(train_facts, truncation=True, padding=True)
val_encodings = tokenizer(val_winners, truncation=True, padding=True)
train_dataset = TextDataset(train_encodings, train_winners)
val_dataset = TextDataset(val_encodings, val_winners)
```

where the val and train facts and winners are results of train_test_split. I then run the following model:

```
#Load pretrained model
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=2)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="test_trainer", 
    logging_dir='logs', 
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,
    num_train_epochs=15,
    logging_steps=50,
)
#metric = evaluate.load("accuracy", "precision", "recall", "f1")
metric = evaluate.load("accuracy")
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

class CustomTrainer(Trainer):
  # Define custom loss function
    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        labels = inputs.get('labels')
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        logits = outputs.get('logits')
        loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.model.config.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss

trainer = CustomTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

However, running through 9 of the 15 epochs I get roughly the same validation and training loss and exactly the same accuracy. This seems fishy to me and I am unsure as to why this may be happening or if I should be worried. Here are the results:

| Epoch | Training Loss | Validation Loss | Accuracy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.646300 | 0.646156 | 0.665519 |
| 2 | 0.630000 | 0.637633 | 0.665519 |
| 3 | 0.636500 | 0.638668 | 0.665519 |
| 4 | 0.650700 | 0.634423 | 0.665519 |
| 5 | 0.642900 | 0.642386 | 0.665519 |
| 6 | 0.650900 | 0.643574 | 0.665519 |
| 7 | 0.666300 | 0.647135 | 0.665519 |
| 8 | 0.643200 | 0.638836 | 0.665519 |
| 9 | 0.642800 | 0.638740 | 0.665519 |

Comment: Training loss, higher than validation loss, try looking at 49th minute https://youtu.be/F1ka6a13S9I?t=2975 =)

Comment: Hint: Increase/Decrease learning rate, increase `gradient_accumulation_steps`. May the neurons be in your favor!

Comment: Thank you so much. Currently looking at ways to ensure my training and test data are similar as well as tuning gradient steps and LR @alvas